Migrating Spring project to Spring Boot and Java Upgrade with OpenRewrite
I have a legacy Spring project that I want to migrate to Spring Boot, and at the same time, I want to upgrade the Java version used in the project. I have seen various approaches specific to Spring Boot to Spring Boot for this migration, but I am particularly interested in using OpenRewrite for this task.
Is it possible to migrate a Spring project to Spring Boot using OpenRewrite? If so, what are the steps involved in achieving this migration? Are there any specific OpenRewrite recipes or tools that can help with this process?
I would appreciate any guidance or examples of how to perform this migration using OpenRewrite.
So far, I have:
Explored the OpenRewrite documentation and GitHub repository to understand the basic concepts and available recipes.
Attempted to apply some general OpenRewrite recipes for Java code modernization, which worked for upgrading the Java version.
Looked for specific OpenRewrite recipes related to migrating from Spring to Spring Boot but couldn't find a comprehensive guide or set of recipes.
I was expecting to find a straightforward set of steps or a specific recipe within OpenRewrite that could handle the migration of a legacy Spring project to Spring Boot. However, I am not sure if such a recipe exists or if I need to create custom recipes for this purpose.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Looks like you're looking for this requested recipe:
Add recipe to migrate projects from Spring Framework to using Spring Boot
That link also contains the first steps if you wish to get involved. Automating these changes is a great way to speed up your work, and ensure the changes are applied consistently across different projects.
